# How to resolve path for style.css that is included in index.html file in Java socket programming

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to create an http server using Java socket programming.

Let's say I am serving static files (html, js, css, etc.) from a particular directory called "web". Let's say I have another directory "hello" inside "web".

When a request comes from client or browser as /hello or /hello/ then I show index.html file that is kept under "hello" directory. So let's assume "hello" is the context path.

Now My index.html file includes a style.css. So requests that come from client are /hello and /style.css, respectively but here I don't have the full path for style.css file.

So how would I know that style.css file should be served from "hello" directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the document was served from `/hello/` (with a trailing slash) and references a resource `style.css`, the browser will request `/hello/style.css`. No additional logic is required in the server.

If the document is served from `/hello` (without a trailing slash) and references the resource `style.css`, the browser will request `/style.css`. Instead of serving your document at this address, consider serving a HTTP redirect to `/hello/`, both to solve the resource naming problem and to keep URLs consistent.

You can also reference the resource as `/hello/style.css`, avoiding the problem entirely.

Comment: You can also reference the resource as /hello/style.css, avoiding the problem entirely. - actually I don't want to hardcode the value because if there are multiple web apps like hello then it would be difficult to maintain, I think.

Comment: But one thing, I can't assume that request will come from client with trailing slash, so then how it would be resolved?

Comment: By redirecting requests from `/hello` to `/hello/`.